# JSON error when php responses

Tags: java, android, json, arrays, jsonexception

I have a problem with JSON.

I've got this service, that connect to php and send me data in json format.
All was ok (months ago), but today I modified a little thing and don't work.

I add a call function to simply compare 2 jSon arrays and to create another one with the elements that are in one but no in other.

this is the code of service:

```
public class GroupsTaskAlarmChecker extends Service implements Runnable {

public void run() {
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("role", role));

try
{               
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://blablabla.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        noInternet=false;

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            noInternet=true;
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{                
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        result=sb.toString();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        noInternet=true;
    }

    jArray2= result;
    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);

if (jArray2.equals(groupList) || noInternet) {
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(NO_CHANGE);
}
else {
    if (!noInternet)
        {
            try {
                prepareForNewImage(jArray2);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    Editor e = mPrefs.edit();
    e.putString("groupList", jArray2);
    e.commit();
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(THERE_ARE_CHANGE);
}
}

public void prepareForNewImage(String j) throws JSONException {
    String gL = mPrefs.getString("groupList", null);
    Log.e("string j",j);
    String jA = "";
    jA=j;
    if(!gL.equals(null)) {
    JSONArray gL2 = new JSONArray(gL);
    JSONArray jA2 = new JSONArray(jA);
    boolean is = false;
    for(int i=0;i<jA2.length();i++){
        JSONObject json_data2 = jA2.getJSONObject(i);
        String gId_jA2=json_data2.getString("groupId");
        for(int k=0;i<gL2.length();k++){
            JSONObject json_data = gL2.getJSONObject(k);
            String gId_gL2=json_data.getString("groupId");
            if (gId_gL2.equals(gId_jA2))
                is=true;
        }
        if (!is)
        {
            is=false;
            newGroups.put(json_data2);          
        }
    Log.i("loop","end of first loop");
    }

        Editor e = mPrefs.edit();
        e.putString("newGroups", newGroups.toString());
        e.commit();
    }
    }
```

And this is my new logCat:

```
03-06 15:44:54.243: W/System.err(19868): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
03-06 15:44:54.253: W/System.err(19868):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
03-06 15:44:54.253: W/System.err(19868):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
03-06 15:44:54.253: W/System.err(19868):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>    (JSONArray.java:87)
03-06 15:44:54.253: W/System.err(19868):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
03-06 15:44:54.253: W/System.err(19868):    at com.org.tfc_android.GroupsTaskAlarmChecker.prepareForNewImage(GroupsTaskAlarmChecker.java:162)
03-06 15:44:54.253: W/System.err(19868):    at com.org.tfc_android.GroupsTaskAlarmChecker.run(GroupsTaskAlarmChecker.java:139)
03-06 15:44:54.253: W/System.err(19868):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

somebody could help me? Thank You in advance.

Comment: your array comparison implementation is naive. It's complexity is o(n²). I would sort both arrays on the groupid (o(log(n)), which allows you to make a o(n) comparison (if g1[i] == g2[k] => add; else if g1[i] < g2[k] => i++; else if g1[i] > g2[k] => k++;)

Comment: thank you @njzk2 .You are right, I'll make it after if I have time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You flubbed your index check here:

`for(int k=0;i<gL2.length();k++){`
 `------------^`

You should be using `k`, not `i`. On a side note, you have alot of repetitive code that you could probably glean out of your code (eg, the repeated calls to `mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);`.

Comment: You are right about variable k.
Also I have delete multiple mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0); except the first. Thanks for it.

But still error JSONException: end of input at character 0 of
and it seems to be in this line:

JSONArray gL2 = new JSONArray(gL);

thats the first line I create new Json in my function.
Do you know why can be this? :/

Comment: You'll want to verify the string you are getting back from your preferences class (`String gL = mPrefs.getString("groupList", null);`), to verify that it is not empty.

Comment: You are right.
I had  if(!gL.equals(null))   instead of   if(!gL.equals("")) and was wrong because before (in other activity) I initialize that SharedPreferences to "".
Furthermore I was wrong in FORS loop because I never put variable "is" to false, and then never entry to the IF and because that (apart of another logic errors), my variable JSONArray newGroups always was empty.
Thank you very much for your help @Perception

Comment: No problem! Good luck with the rest of the project.